# Grouping Data with the same values on multiple properties

Tags: c#, linq, intersection, venn-diagram

I have a list of objects with data. In order to analyze the data, n amount of properties must match and when they don't match, must be removed. This is regardless of the value of the properties, just that they are equal

For example:

| C1 | C2 | C3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bob | 3 | ... |
| 1 | bob | 3 | ... |
| 1 | bill | 3 | ... (this row would be removed) |
| 1 | bob | 10 | ... (this row would be removed) |
| 1 | bob | 3 | ... |

I'm somewhat stuck and keep thinking I need to brute-force this. Is there anything in linq that can help? Self intersections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have an `IEnumerable` called `items` that contains all of your rows, and your property names are `C1`, `C2`, and `C3`, you could use `GroupBy` to do something like this:

```
var result = items
   .GroupBy(item => (item.C1, item.C2, item.C3))
   .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
   .SelectMany(group => group);
```

This will do the following:

- `.GroupBy(item => (item.C1, item.C2, item.C3))` - create groups based on the three columns that you specified - any items where the three values are the same will be grouped together
- `.Where(group => group.Count() > 1)` - filter out any groups that only have one item
- `.SelectMany(group => group)` - "flatten" the groups back into a single list

You may need to adjust this so that it works with the actual types you are using, but hopefully you get the general idea.